# Routing issue in react JavaScript

Tags: reactjs, mern

Here is my code of app.js and the error occurring is:

> Module not found: Error: Cannot find file: 'index.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\node_modules\React\react'.

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Login from "./components/LoginPage/loginPage";
import Homepage from "./components/HomePage/homepage";
import Register from "./components/Register/register";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Homepage />
      <Login />
      <Register />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is react exist in node_modules? Try in your project folder

`npm install`

Comment: Thank you for replying but i resolved this issue ... i had import react wrong (import react from "React") instead of import react from "react"